Screen Reader "run at start" option is cleared after reboot in Ubuntu 24.04 Mate beta
This should be a bug. But I don't know where I should report. It doesn't crash and I don't know which package this bug belongs to.
Here is the reproduce steps:

Login Ubuntu 24.04 Mate beta
Menu->Preferences->Assistive Technologies->Preferred Applications->check "Run at start" (below Orca Screen Reader)
Reboot
Screen Reader is not run at start and the item checked at step 2 is unchecked.

This issue affects all blind users. They need to start screen reader manually with shortcut SUPER+ALT+s at start.

Ubuntu 24.04 (noble) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the development release Ubuntu noble and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu noble you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc.  This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues, and please note the release is still in beta

If you don't want to file a bug report (see prior comment for details on using launchpad which is used for all Ubuntu & flavor deb packages, though Ubuntu-MATE also use Github for their packages), you could also file at the Ubuntu MATE discourse site (https://ubuntu-mate.community/) so Ubuntu-MATE members & developers actually see the report. This is a user support site.   FYI:  I'm pretty sure I saw discussion on this or similar in the last 48 hours, which included wimpy or the lead of Ubuntu-MATE (either IRC or Matrix) but reporting where it can be tracked is best; not user support sites

I think I have found some clues why the option is restore after reboot. I ignored a crash Window at boot. speech-dispatcher crashes at start. So Orca fail to launch. When Orca fail to launch, the screen reader option will be turned off.
It may not be a problem of speech-dispatcher of the beta version because I have installed a modified version. I will take a deeper investigation.
